# Is there anyway to change the default Grails service naming convention?

Tags: grails

I'd like to create a Grails services without using the *Service postfix convention for class names (e.g. name my class Scheduler instead of ScheduleService). Is there anyway over-ride Grails default behaviour and treat any object in the `grails-app/service` directory as a Grails service?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, but if the reason is that you want to use a different name for the bean, you can try to register an alias for scheduleService.
According to a comment [on this page](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=85) you should be able to add this to resources.groovy:

```
springConfig.addAlias('scheduler','scheduleService')
```

Haven't tried it myself, though, and didn't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can, just do in resources.groovy

```
scheduler(YourCustomSchedulerClassname){ b->
    // config
}
```

Then you can do anywhere else

```
class MyService {
    def scheduler
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think that's possible. Cause it's part of the 'convention' implied in the grails framework.

Answer (score 1):

Grails services are registered as beans with a plugin, believe it or not, so you should be able to accomplish this by creating your own plugin.

Have a look at [grails-plugin-services source](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-services/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/services/ServicesGrailsPlugin.groovy). You can see that watched services are hardwired in with this line:

```
def watchedResources = ["file:./grails-app/services/**/*Service.groovy",
                        "file:./plugins/*/grails-app/services/**/*Service.groovy"]
```

Now, despite the fact that it's possible, it may require a bit of work, and it may be a bad idea. I really don't know. I have no idea if Grails would freak out if you essentially copied the services plugin, changed `watchedResources` and wrapped it up in your own plugin.

I just glanced through the grails docs and the section on [Artefacts](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#artefactApi) should also be useful.

If you're just looking for an easier way to reference your services, do this:

```
def painfullyLongNameService
def getNoPain() {return painfullyLongNameService}

noPain.yourServiceFunction()
```